# C++ Sudoku Solver

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

Need help figuring out what is wrong with the `readPuzzle` and `printPuzzle` functions. `SetOfSmallInts` is a set containing `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}` or any combination of those numbers. `singletonSet(s)` store a single number s in a set. No matter what input I run on the program it only out puts 1's. Even if all the inputs are '-' the output is 81 1's. Any suggestions? The Puzzle type in main make an array of `SetofSmallInts [9][9]`.

```
//==============================================================
//                      readPuzzle
//==============================================================
// Reads in puzzle p from the standard input.
//==============================================================

void readPuzzle(Puzzle p)
{
   int i, j;
   SetOfSmallInts s;
   s = rangeSet(1, 9);
   char n;

   for(i = 0; i < 9; i++)
   {
      for(j = 0; j < 9; j++) 
      {
       n = scanf("%c", &n);  
       if (n == '-')
       {
         p[i][j]= s;
       }
       else if(n==1 || n==2 || n==3 || n==4 || n==5 || n==6 ||
               n==7 || n==8 || n==9)
      {
         p[i][j]= singletonSet(n);
      }
      }
   }      
}


//==============================================================
//                      printPuzzle
//==============================================================
// Prints in puzzle p.
//==============================================================
void printPuzzle(Puzzle p)
{
   int i, j, s;
   SetOfSmallInts x;

   for(i = 0; i < 9; i++)
   {
      for(j = 0; j < 9; j++)
      {
         x = p[i][j];
         if(isEmpty(x)) 
         {
            printf("%i ", 0);
         }
         else if(isSingleton(x)) //returns true if x hold Singleton set
         {
            s = smallest(x); // returns the smallest member of s
            printf("%i ", s);
         }
         else
         {
            printf("%c ", '-');
         }
      }
   }
}  

//==============================================================
//                      showPuzzle
//==============================================================
// Shows in puzzle p in a format that can be used for debugging
//==============================================================


//==============================================================
//                   main
//==============================================================

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   Puzzle p;
   readPuzzle(p);
   printPuzzle(p);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `n = scanf("%c", &n);` is your problem. This fills n with how many arguments were fulfilled and not with what you scanned in.

Comment: I.e. n is always 1 if that succeeds, 0 if not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you  just need `scanf("%c", &n)`

also n is a char

so

```
else if(n==1 || n==2 || n==3 || n==4 || n==5 || n==6 ||
               n==7 || n==8 || n==9)
```

need to do `n == '1'`  etc etc

or `else if( n >= '1' && n <= '9')`

then you'll probably need

```
p[i][j]= singletonSet(n - '0');
```

Comment: Thanks that did make it read in the numbers. but it is also reading in spaces and storing 0's in the spots of spaces. Therefore it does not finish reading the puzzle because some of the spaces are taken up with 0's that shouldnt be there.

Answer (score 5):

`n = scanf("%c", &n);`

scanf returns the number of items scanned.  You just want

```
scanf("%c", &n);
```

Comment: Or, better yet `x = scanf("%c", &n); if (x != 1) { do error stuff };`